# Passing A Jsx component to another jsx component as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I'm passing a jsx component(A) to another component(B) as a prop, like this:

```
import A from "A.jsx";
import B from "B.jsx";
...
class MyClass extends React{
...
  render(){
    return <B customContent={A} />
  };
}
```

when component B gets updated in React life-cycle, will A gets updated too?

Comment: no because each component have their  life-cycle, of course when B mount, A will mount to , but it will react to owns methods, unitl you pass props to 'A' in 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

In React when a component is rendered all its **child components** will be rendered too .

In your case when you pass component A to B as an attribute **component A** will be passed to **Component B** as a regular object and will not be rendered .

for ex: if you passed function instead of component A it will not be executed untill you call it from the component B.

if you need to render a component inside another dynamically you should use **children** property on the **props** object let me show you :

**At My Class**

```
  class MyClass extends React{
    ...
      render(){
        return <B > 

                 <A />

               </B>
      };
    }
```

**At Component B**

You can do the following :

```
 class B extends Component{
    ...
      render(){
        return
                <React.Fragment> 

                 {this.props.children}

               </React.Fragment>
      };
    }
```